# Why the class of all inductive sets is not a set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Page 66, Set Theory of - Herbert B. Enderton, *Elements of Set Theory*.

It says "but the class of all inductive sets is not a set."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA If $\omega$ does not exist, then the class of all inductive sets is a set. It is the empty set. I think the OP is working in $\text{ZFC}$ (in particular with the infinity axiom) and he or she wants to see that in this setting this class is not a set. This is more along the line of tetori's interpretation.

Comment: @William - you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every limit ordinal is inductive, and the class of all limit ordinals is not a set. However if the class of all inductive set is a set, then the class of all limit ordinals is also a set, a contradiction.