# Collection of all inductive Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is collections of all inductive sets is a set or proper class? And how to prove this?
where inductive set is a set given from axiom of infinity

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765633/why-the-class-of-all-inductive-sets-is-not-a-set/765651

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT:** Every limit ordinal is inductive.

**ANOTHER HINT:** Every $V_\alpha$ is inductive when $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal.

**YET ANOTHER HINT:** Given a set $x$, show that there is a minimal inductive set such that $x$ is an element of that set. Suppose now that there was a set of all inductive sets, and use this hint to arrive at a contradiction.

Comment: Is the collection of limit ordinals a set? The notation $V_\alpha$ is the set of those with von Neumann rank $<\alpha$. If you don't know what that means, then never mind, and focus on the other hints instead.

Comment: Ok from first hint: Since every limit ordinal is inductive and as each cardinal no. is limit ordinal but since collection of all cardinal is not a set. Hence collection of all inductive sets can't be set. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. But you should also prove the hint.

Comment: Ok this I know I need to prove the result. I'll do it and get back here only. May you please explain third hint also a little bit?

Comment: You can somewhat simplify the third hint.